# Infinite finitely presented simple group (or more generally with trivial profinite completion) that is not amalgamated free product

Tags: gr.group-theory, geometric-group-theory

As is described in the title. Is there a finitely presented group $G$, with trivial profinite completion $\widehat{G}=0$, which is not amalgamated free product?

For example, the famous example Higman groups are all amalgamated free product.

Comment: Thompson’s groups T and V are finitely presented infinite simple groups with Serre’s property FA; in particular, they don’t split.

Comment: Any finite simple group clearly has property FA, and hence is not an amalgamated free product.

Comment: @IgorBelegradek, that's true, but a finite simple group is equal to its profinite completion.

Comment: Among infinite finitely presented simple groups, it is usually harder to to find non-FA groups than FA-groups. The first non-FA such groups are Burger-Mozes' groups. Checking that groups such as Thompson's group T or V have FA is quite easy. Also I'm not sure what is meant by "famous Higman groups". There's one famous Higman group (indeed an amalgam), generalizations (not called Higman groups as far as I know), and unrelated "Thompson-Higman groups" (which have FA).

Comment: It's always misleading when the question in the text does not match that in the title (of course the question can specify, but here it's the contrary, as simple groups are mentioned in the title and not the text).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm going to flesh out my comment above to an answer. [Thompson's groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thompson_groups) $T$ and $V$ are famous examples of finitely presented infinite simple groups.

In [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/0708.1334) paper of Dan Farley, it is shown that $T$ and $V$ have Serre's property FA, which means that every time they act on a tree there is a global fixed point. (Farley says that this statement is originally due to Ken Brown.) When applied to the Bass--Serre tree of a  splitting, it follows that any such splitting of $T$ or $V$ is trivial.

Comment: Just for information: Thompson's group $V$ satisfies stronger fixed-point properties. Two natural extensions of Serre's property FA are fixed-point properties for Gromov-hyperbolic spaces and for higher dimensional CAT(0) spaces. See arxiv.org/abs/1804.10506 and arxiv.org/abs/1804.01791.